# Images with razor asp.net mvc inside JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor

I need to dynamically insert an image in my JS code. In my Razor template I have:

```
@section Includes {  
      <script type="text/javascript">   


        var imgPath = "@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")";
        alert(imgPath);

      </script>

}
```

Then in my JS I have:

```
 insertImg = "";
  if (response[i].someFlag == 'Y') {

                        insertImg = "<img src=\"" + imgPath + "/imgToInsert.gif\" width=\"6px\" height=\"10px\" />";
                    }
```

But it doesn't work - it will not find the image. The image is stored in /Content/img folder...

What am I doing wrong? I am guessing it is because it is mapping the image from Js script..looks like I will have to hardcode it?

Comment: Alert or console.log the following to see if there are too many slashes `" + imgPath + "/imgToInsert.gif"`

Comment: That is what it was! can you answer it so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert or console.log the following to see if there are too many slashes 
`" + imgPath + "/imgToInsert.gif"`

Answer (score 0):

It might be advantageous to use the [MVC TagBuilder Class](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs) to build your image tags instead of using a string *concatenations*.  Lets you build tags dynamically and makes sure they are well-formed.  Most likely your tag is not well-formed.